# Testing Node with Superagent and Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, superagent

when I run this code below, the user is logged in and the browser is redirected to a new route `home`. How do I structure the test below to validate that `/home` is being redirected to.

The application is working fine, I am just trying to get my test cases in order.

Thanks

```
   it('should login user',
    function(done) {
        request
        .post(url.parse('http://localhost:3000/login'))
        .send({
            userName: "load@xyz.com", password: "xyzpassword"
        })
        .end(function(res) {
            res.statusCode.should.equal(302);
            done();
        })
    });
```

additional information... the code works but is failing with the stackdump so I am unable to verify that the test is successful or not

```
 1) authentication_tests should login user:
     TypeError: first argument must be a string, Array, or Buffer
      at ClientRequest.write (http.js:601:11)
      at ClientRequest.end (http.js:681:16)
      at Request.end (/Users/aaronksaunders/dev/node_stuff/sqchic/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:602:7)
      at Request.redirect (/Users/aaronksaunders/dev/node_stuff/sqchic/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:459:8)
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/aaronksaunders/dev/node_stuff/sqchic/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:569:49)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:64:17)
      at HTTPParser.<anonymous> (http.js:1349:9)
      at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:108:31)
      at Socket.ondata (http.js:1226:22)
      at Socket._onReadable (net.js:683:27)
      at IOWatcher.onReadable (net.js:177:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [superagent docs](http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/)

> Response header fields
>
> The res.header contains an object of parsed header fields, lowercasing field names much like node does. For example res.header['content-length'].

So you can check along the lines of:

```
(/home$/).test res.header['location']
```

For your redirect test case.

Comment: the thing is that the code works, but the test harness is failing with this stack dump, see edits above

Comment: That's probably because you are passing the object returned from url.parse to request.post. Just pass the URL as a string directly to request.post.